# Call an abstracts class method

Tags: java, methods, call, abstract

im trying to call a method from an abstract class but i dont know where im wrong.
This is the abstract class:

```
public abstract class Sim implements Runnable {
    public Sim(String id, String type, Buffer<Measure>queue){
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.midnight = computeMidnightMilliseconds();
    }

    public void stopMe() {
        stopCondition = true;
    }
}
```

i wanna call the method stopMe(), i use the code bellow

```
public class StopThread extends Sim  {
    protected  StopThread(){super ();}//what should i put here?

    @Override
    public  void run(){
        stopMe();
    }

    @Override
    public void stopMe() {
        stopCondition = true;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated 
 Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what's the issue here? are you getting an exception?

Comment: @nlloyd yes the first problem is that that super needs params, whats should i put there? i'saw in another example they usually use super when extend an abstract class but im not sure about the logic they use

Comment: can you post the reference to that example

Comment: @asteriskNinja it's part of a project im actually developing. the idea is that i have a thread which generates data as long as stopCondition is true. now i wanna use the stopMe method to stop the data generation. so i just wanna chang the stopCondition value to false

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna call the super class's method, just use `super.stopMe()`. There is no need for you to override the `stopMe` method in `StopThread` since the function does the same thing in your super class `Sim`.

In your `StopThread` class's constructor method, you can pass in these parameters as well. It will look like:

```
public StopThread(String id, String type, Buffer<Measure> queue) {
    super(id, type, queue);
}
```

Comment: thank u for answering, actually im not very clear about how super works. but if i try to change it from protected  StopThread(){super ();} to protected  StopThread(){
super.stopMeGently();} it says : " there is no default constructor available in Sim class "

Comment: @Anja.M super just means the instance of the class you extended, when you call super(), it calls the super class's constructor. if you call super.someMethod() , then it call's that method.

Comment: That makes sense now. but i still dot get it why it says there is no default constructor available in Sim class? where am i wrong?

Comment: @Anja.M It's because the only constructor of you `Sim` class is a 3 parameter one. You need to call it and pass in 3 parameters to initialize the instance fields as what I write in my answer.

Comment: oh i got it now finally :)  so it has to be something like :                                 public class StopThread extends Sim  {
    public StopThread(String id, String type, Buffer<Measure> queue) {
        super(id, type, queue);
    }
        @Override
    public  void run(){
        stopMeGently();
    }                                                                                                               than i have to call it like : 
 StopThread stopThread = new StopThread(idnumber,type,InnerBuffer.getInstance());
                stopThread.stopMeGently();

Comment: @Anja.M Yes, so in a inheritance tree of class, each class should take care of its initialization, that's why you need to call `super()` to initialize the instance fields defined in the super class. Since your super class `Sim` needs 3 parameters to initialize itself, then you have to pass 3 parameters to `super()`.

Comment: it gives no errors now but when executed doesnt make what it has to :/  do u think i probably use wrong params when i call it ?  im sorry but im not very good in java programming

Comment: @Anja.M Then you should debug it.

Answer (score 0):

> protected  StopThread(){super ();}//what should i put here?

you should give a ***String id*** a ***String type*** and a  ***Buffer queue*** what ever that is...

## Example:

```
public class StopThread extends Sim  {
protected  StopThread(){
    super(foo.getId(), foo.getType(), foo.getQueue);
}


@Override
public  void run(){
    while(!stopMe()){
        /// your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: well but how can i give it the String id a String type and a Buffer queue if i have them saved as variables in another class?  Buffer is an interface                                                                                                          public interface Buffer<T> {
    void add(T t);
    List<T> readElements();
}

Comment: thank u , i got the logic of that. So when i call it i have to do somthing like : StopThread stopThread = new StopThread(idnumber,type,InnerBuffer.getInstance());
                stopThread.stopMeGently(); ? it does nothing :/

Comment: is stopCondition a variable in the SuperClass isnt??

Comment: yea its declared....  protected volatile boolean stopCondition = false;

Comment: look at the update... do you have  in the run something like I wrote?

Comment: actually the idea is that i have a thread which generates data as long as stopCondition is true. now i wanna use the stopMe method to stop the data generation. so that part while(!stopMe()) exists in another class, none of the above